# Jhipster 4 generated app doesn't reflect changes in browser

Tags: spring, angular, jhipster

I have tried following things -

- To change in webpack.dev.js - as set reload : true

```
new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            }
        }, {
            reload: true
        })
```

Also tried with **yarn start** but this solution also not worked.

Can Anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: Could you clarify? After generation you don't have anything special to do run yarn start, it listens on port 9000 and proxifies to spring boot app on port 8080 that you run with mvnw or gradlew. Both must be running, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: Both are running, I am trying with it also, page is showing by default values were added but today I have changed in home.component.html as <p>hiii!!</p> but this element is not reflecting on browser when I reload the page.

Comment: In the browser which URL are you accessing?

Comment: I have tried with localhost:8080, localhost:9060 and localhost:9000, but not getting my changes in browser.

Comment: It should be 9000, what is port 9060 for? Config in webpack.dev.js should stay as it is, don't you see any log in yarn start window?

Comment: yes now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple language go to jhiTranslate json files under src.main.webapp.i18n.en(for English) and update the values.